# Fastest way to access previous row in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I need to access the previous row for a key in Redshift to get a value, then subtract it from the current value.

This works perfectly fine, but it's just too slow for what I need.

```
select customer_id,
      date,
      amount,
      lag(amount) over (partition by customer_id order by date asc) as lag_amount,
      amount - lag_amount as delta
from tbl
```

I have to write this for 6 other columns, in a table that is about 100 million rows.

I've changed the source table sort key to be customer_id, date (in that order), thinking this would help.

I've tried different column compression encodings, but I didn't get a considerable performance improvement.

Any ideas?

Comment: This would be fairly easy to handle on databases which support column indices, but RedShift does not support that.

Answer (score 1):

With your partition on customer_id you will do best if this is the distribution key of the table.  This will make each partition node local and should speed this up considerably.  I'd recommend keeping only date as you sort key.